# Need some help to set up PostgreSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql

Don't want to bore you with long description of my problem, but I ended up having two Postgres databases on one Ubuntu OS (old and new versions, just because I'm not too smart in Linux).

Postgres 1 is not set up properly, I couldn't access it etc. But it boots by default and is in all default locations.

Postgres 2 is the one I want to use, my PGAdmin can see it, it has users, tables etc. But it's installed under this directory:

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to delete Postgres1 and make Postgres2 boot by default.

I tried to run this:

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/data
```

And it gave me permission denied error.

I do see some Postgres processes when I do grep command.

For now the only option I see is to reinstall my Ubuntu and try installing Postgres again. But that is so much work that I thought maybe someone could look into my issue before I do that.

Will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: `And it gave me permission denied error.` That is not a very detailed description of the problem. Is the data directory `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/data` owned by user=postgres, group=postgres ?

Comment: You need to bore us with the long description.  How did you install postgresql  is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are you installed both as deb packages and they are running on different ports, right?

Your proper approach is to use `apt-get` to remove the one you don't want, then edit the postgresql.conf to change the port of the one you want to 5432, then restart the service.

Note you cannot run `pg_ctl` as root.  This is because PostgreSQL will not run as a system superuser.

Comment: You also can't usually run it as your normal user account if the database is owned by the `postgres` user; use `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl` if that's the case.

Comment: No, the packages would not have installed in `/opt`.